# Providing personal access token on GitHub command line

Tags: macos, github, command-line

I enabled two factor authentication on my GitHub account and now I can't push to my repositories. I had previously cloned my repositories to my computer and I have been pushing and pulling successfully until I enabled two factor authentication.

I have read up on this problem and I have found that I need to change the SSH to be `git@github.com/repositoryName`, and I have done this. I have also read that I need to generate a personal access token (PAT) which I have also done.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to provide this new token to the repository on the command line. I am running OS X v10.11 (El Capitan) and ITerm 2.

The error I am getting is:

```
 Error: Repository not found.
 fatal: could not read from remote repository.

 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to regenerate the SSH keys on top of the other steps you took. Run

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Then run

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

and paste the contents into the SSH keys client within GitHub to add the key to GitHub.